# How to add the prototype library in all web pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I have several pages that using the prototype library, so, I added " javascript_include_tag 'prototype'" in my RoR application. But I want to DRY my code. Is there any way, like a root page, and all view is subclass from this page, that allow me to add this once, and all my view will get the javascript_include_tag 'prototype' automatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the application layout file which is `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. All of your view templates will use this layout and therefore include the JavaScript, unless you override with a controller-specific layout or other layout.

- [This Rails Guide explains about layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) in more detail.